# LINQ Find Null Objects in List

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a `List<MyList>` of objects.

`MyList` also has in it several Lists and one might be called `List<Defect>`.

`List<Defect>` can contain multiple defects one or more of which might be null.

How can I return a count of MyList items where MyList.Defects contains a null object?

I know I can do a foreach and check every item but is there a LINQ way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*How can I return a count of MyList items where MyList.Defects contains a null object?*

```
return myLists.Count(ml => ml.Defects.Contains(null));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
return myLists.Count(ml => ml.Defects.Any(d => d==null));
```

Comment: +1 Whilst I think this solution is probably easier to read, I like @mquander's solution a little better for its brevity.  Thank you any way @Joel.